# shapely polygon leaves traces of other poly geometries after unary_union

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I am trying to dissolve poly from a shapefile with unary_union and at times I am left with a poly that looks like this:[image: StrangePoly]

You can see the lingering line geometries left inside of the poly.  I have been able to drill down to the xy coords of the exterior and build a new polygon from that. This has removed the chatter that is shown in the interior of the poly, but using the exterior coords leaves me with a problem detailed in the image below that is a zoom from the red box above:

[image: WonkyLine]

There are a couple of lines like this that remain in the exterior ring, is there a way that I can remove them?

Comment: Is there a link to the duplicate?  I'd really like to know how this was resolved. Thanks

Comment: the link above fixed the problem I was seeing using the join_style keyword in multiple buffers. Good stuff!